# How to track outcoming requests in Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, oauth-2.0

I'm running [OAuth2 example](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) which makes requests on GitHub. The problem is that the requests go not from browser, but from backend under the hood. So how to track/log them (just to see they exist)?

Answer (score 0):

```
logging:
  level:
   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate: DEBUG
```